# Open Popup from servlet or jsf managed bean?

Tags: java, popup

Is there any way to open a popup from a servlet
I have an asynchronous process running , and I need to somehow notify the user when finished, without having to refresh the page

any ideas ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Without having to refresh the page"

That's what Ajax is all about I suggest that you take a look to some Ajax enable JSF framework, like [Richfaces](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces), if you're using [JSF 2.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu3/index.html) you can use Ajax behavior by default.

With Richfaces you can use the `<a4j:poll>` to check after some period of time if the asynchronous process have finished, you can then re-render the appropriate message.

```
 <a4j:poll interval="1000" enabled="#{notificationBean.isTaskComplete}"
                reRender="completeMessagePanel" />
```

Thats the general Idea.

Comment: yes, that's right, i'm using icefaces
i think i could make a function that constantly ask if the process has finish, like an alert system, I thought that could be done from the servlet

Comment: Hi, I dont know much icefaces, but it seems that you can have what they call a "server-initiated rendering" http://www.icefaces.org/docs/v1_8_2/htmlguide/devguide/AdvancedTopics2.html#1075177. Probably you can do the same from your managed bean, once and your process have finished.